# Mobile menu doesn't scroll

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The mobile page works just like i wanted it to work but the problem is when i open site navigation, main contect is sliding down and navigation is static. i cant scroll navigation.. is it anyway that i could scroll navigation only? the site where is problem is `www.budivelik.hr` any idea?

```css
  body > .main-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -210px;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 80px;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 210px;
    z-index: 101;
    background: #333333;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    z-index: 150;
    -webkit-user-select:  none;
    -moz-user-select:     none;
    -ms-user-select:      none;
    -o-user-select:       none;
    user-select:          none;
  }

  .main-nav.active-menu {
    left: 0;
  }

  .main-header .nav-bar {
    display: block;
  }

  body.menu-effect .boxed-view {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
   -webkit-transform: translate(200px,0);
   z-index: 100;
   position: relative;
  }

  body > .main-nav > ul,
  body > .main-nav > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }

  body > .main-nav > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    padding: 20px 11px 18px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }

  body .mobile-menu-button {
    display: block;
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    margin: auto;
    padding:  1px 5px;

    font-size: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 76px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 62px;
    background: url("../images/icons/menu-icon.png") no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
  }

  body .woocommerce-page .mobile-menu-button{
    background: url("../images/icons/white-menu-icon.png") no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    
    right: 132px;
  }

  .mobile-menu-button:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .product .summary{
      padding: 0 20px;
  }

  .main-header .socials{
    margin: 12px 0 0;
  }

  .social-links > li a {
      max-height: 48px;
      width: 36px;
  }

  .main-slider .sneakers{
    left: 20%;
  }

  .recommend-block{
    margin-top: 40px;
  }

  .gallery-slider .quarter-size .gallery-photo-desc > div .zoom-image{
      transform: scale(0.8) translate(0px, -70%);
  }


}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px){
    .big-footer .sportify-wrap{
        display: none;
    }

    .big-footer .footer-block{
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .contact-form label{
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .error-box .sneakers-block{
        padding-top: 60px;
    }

    .new-arrivals > .row > div{
        width: 25%;
    }

    .new-arrivals > .row > div:nth-child(5){
        border-top: medium none;
    }

    .new-arrivals > .row > div:nth-child(5n+1){
        border-left: medium none;
    }

    .new-arrivals > .row > div:nth-child(4n+1){
       border-left: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    }

    .team-item header a{
      width: 50%;
    }

    .team-list > li{
      width: 50%;
    }

    .shop-slider .round-offer{
        left: 50%;
    }

    .shop-slider .round-offer{
        width: 286px;
        height: 286px;
        left: 40%;
    }

    .shop-slider .round-offer:before{
        width: 334px;
        height: 334px;
    }

    .member-box figure img{
      width: 100%;
    }

    .commentlist > li .children{
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .member-box .content{
      min-height: 100px !important;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .main-header .ad{
        margin-top: 18px;
    }

    .main-header .socials{
        display: none;
    }

    .big-footer .footer-block{
        padding-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .big-footer .contact-block{
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
        bottom: auto;
        left: auto;
    }

    .big-footer .contact-block textarea{
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

    .big-footer .contact-block .form-submit{
        text-align: center;
    }

    .filter-box ul li,
    .filter-box > div{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .filter-box ul li a{
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 10px; 
    }

    .timetable thead tr > th:nth-child(1),
    .timetable tbody tr > th{
        display: none;
    }

    .new-arrivals > .row > div{
        width: 50%;
    }

    
    .new-arrivals > .row > div:nth-child(3), 
    .new-arrivals > .row > div:nth-child(4), 
    .new-arrivals > .row > div:nth-child(5){
        border-top: medium none;
    }

    .new-arrivals > .row > div:nth-child(5n+1){
        border-left: medium none;
    }

    .new-arrivals > .row > div:nth-child(2n+1){
       border-left: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    }

    .about-box header .header-block .entry-header{
      position: static;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

    .blog-box figure img{
      width: 100%;
    }

    body .woocommerce-page .mobile-menu-button{
      width: 52px;
      height: 52px;
      right: 160px;
    }

    .news-block .news-list li .row > div:hover:before{
      height: 100%;
    }

    .commentlist > li .children{
      margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .blog-box .blog-items > div{
      width: 100%;
    }


}

@media screen and (max-width: 724px){
    .main-header .ad{
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

      body .mobile-menu-button {
        right: 22px;
      }

      .team-list > li{
        width: 100%;
      }

      .tp-bullets {
          margin-left: 5% !important;
      }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 670px){
    .woo-container .shopping-cart-wrap .coupon-code-block .coupon-field{
        width: 50%;
    }

    .woo-container .shopping-cart-wrap .coupon-code-block .button{
        width: 50%;
    }

    .update-cart{
      float: none;
      text-align: right;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    .nav-bar .identity{
        text-align: center;
    }

    .nav-bar .identity img{
        max-height: 40px;
        max-width: 120px;

    }

    body .woocommerce-page .mobile-menu-button{
      right: 130px;
      width: 42px;
      height: 42px;
      background-position: 0 -2px;
    }

    body .woocommerce-page .search-block{
      display: none;
    }

    body .woocommerce-page header .col-xs-4{
      width: 100%;
    }

    body .woocommerce-page > header .cart-all{
      margin-left: 15px;
    }

    body .woocommerce-page > header .cart-all i,
    body .woocommerce-page > header .cart-all .amount{
      width: 50%;
    }

    body .woocommerce-page > header .col-xs-3{
      width: 100%;
    }

    .show-content > header .col-xs-4{
      width: 100%;
    }

    .show-content > header .ad{
      display: none;
    }

    .page-slider-block ul li .col-xs-6{
      width: 100%;
    }

    .page-slider-box .slider-controls{
      bottom: 30%;
    }

    .checkout_coupon input[type="text"]{
      min-width: 120px !important;
      width: auto !important;
    }


}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .sneakers-block{
        display: none;
    }

    body .woocommerce-page .mobile-menu-button{
      right: 10px;
    }

    .team-item header a{
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px 0 4px 10px;
    }

    .team-item header a br{
      display: none;
    }

    .classes-box .classes{
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
    }

    .classes-box nav .toggle-content .entry-header{
      padding-top: 20px;
      margin-top: 12px;
    }

    .classes-box nav .toggle-content{
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .classes-box .classes-content-block .read-more{
      position: relative;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height: 18px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      padding: 12px 50px 8px 0px
    }

    .box-header .entry-header{

      font-size: 22px;
      line-height: 28px;
    }

    body .mobile-menu-button{
      right: 10px;
    }
}
```

This is my CSS for mobile version of site..

Comment: What happens if you change `body > .main-nav{overflow:hidden}` to `body > .main-nav{overflow:auto}` ??

Comment: still the same problem, i tried auto and scroll and nothing..

Comment: Make sure your cursor is in `.main-nav` class to make it work.

Comment: how do you mean? i didnt understand you..

Comment: Sorry but I have tested in desktop browser Responsive view.

Comment: yes to me it works in desktop browser view and in android web page view but on android chrome mobile version it doesn't work

Comment: Adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` solve your issue ? Also make sure to have `overflow:auto`

Comment: where do i put this webkit? in the .main-nav class on mobile?

Comment: Yes ..Put it there and then test is again

Comment: Do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in your head?

Comment: The -webkit-overflow-scrolling works only for safari mobile..
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling

Comment: i tried but nothing, now i removed padding 80px because that was bug on mobile but as you look on mobile device, problem is that site is zoomed when mobile menu is open and you need to unzoom it to view whole navigation.. how can i make it 100% when is menu open?

Comment: Are you talking about the width of the navigation menu ?

Comment: When i open navigation i now can scroll but not till the end, it comes to here and then i cant go down anymore http://prntscr.com/6yod9k but when i unzoom the whole page then it gives me this http://prntscr.com/6yodhb i want that when navigation its open that it looks like that second picture

Answer (score 2):

To scroll navigation only use following css code

```
@media (max-width: 992px){

    body > .main-nav {
        overflow: scroll;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you test your mobile scrolling?

Comment: On mobile device.. iphone 6, and htc one m8

Comment: For me it works on Nexus 5 both with :scroll and :auto

Comment: in chrome or in some other mobile browser? cause i tested it in chrome

Comment: With latest chrome, try to check if it collides because you're having two <nav> Elements when it comes to mobile view

Comment: i checked it now on my tablet galaxy s3 and there it works but on htc it doesn't work.. where it collides? do i need to delete some code or?

Comment: When you inspect your page at a mobile screen resolution, there are the same two <nav> Elements.
<nav class="main-nav responsive-nav active-menu"></nav>
<nav class="main-nav responsive-nav shop-nav active-menu"></nav>

Try to remove the upper one and check it again on your htc.

Comment: i tried but nothing, now i removed padding 80px because that was bug on mobile but as you look on mobile device, problem is that site is zoomed when mobile menu is open and you need to unzoom it to view whole navigation.. how can i make it 100% when is menu open?